# How to export to FBX without baking animations?

Tags: animation, export

I'm using Blender to make animations that I can use in a Monogame/XNA project. I'm trying to export only the keyframes I set, so I can make custom interpolations in Monogame. However, the FBX exporter seems to force the baking of the animation by setting a keyframe at every frame.

If I uncheck "Baked animation" in the exporter (in Blender v2.77), it seems not to export any keyframe at all.

[image]

I tried to export in COLLADA as well, which does not bake the animation. However, I really need to use the FBX format as I encountered many other problems in COLLADA.

So here is my question, can we export "unbaked"/raw animation in FBX ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **no**; as far as I know, you can't export unbaked raw animation using the FBX exporter.

According to [this post](https://blenderartists.org/t/export-animation-without-baking-animation/673612/7), unchecking *Baked Animation* disables all animation export, meaning the FBX is created without any animation information at all.  I realize it's tantalizing that perhaps disabling baked animation would have somehow exported keyframed "unbaked" animation, but that's unfortunately not the case with this particular exporter.  Unchecking this option works like an *off switch* with respect to animation.  Check it and you get baked animation, uncheck it and you get no animation.  :(

Comment: In principle one could modify the FBX exporter to do the things being asked. You need some programming knowledge or hire someone to do that for you. Just tweaking the settings won't help in this case.